# How can I access dataframe values passed from a flask server to a js function in jinja template?

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, flask, jinja2

Here is my relevant flask code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    symbol = request.form.get('symbol')

    df = api.polygon.historic_agg_v2(symbol, 1, 'minute', _from='2020-06-30', to='2020-07-01').df
    return render_template('graph.html', df = df.to_dict(orient='records'), symbol=symbol)
```

Here is what my dataframe looks like when printed on the python console:

```
      open    high      low    close  volume
timestamp                                                          
2020-06-30 09:29:00-04:00  86.500  86.500  86.2300  86.2300     406
2020-06-30 09:30:00-04:00  86.470  86.580  86.4700  86.5800   39602
2020-06-30 09:31:00-04:00  86.585  86.585  86.5239  86.5239     421
2020-06-30 09:32:00-04:00  86.630  86.630  86.5100  86.5650    1463
2020-06-30 09:33:00-04:00  86.740  86.790  86.7200  86.7900     876
```

Here is some template code getting the df:

```
var df = '{{df}}'
```

Now I log this to console and get something like this:

```
[
  {
    &#39;open&#39;: 86.5,
    &#39;high&#39;: 86.5,
    &#39;low&#39;: 86.23,
    &#39;close&#39;: 86.23,
    &#39;volume&#39;: 406
  },
  {
    &#39;open&#39;: 86.47,
    &#39;high&#39;: 86.58,
    &#39;low&#39;: 86.47,
    &#39;close&#39;: 86.58,
    &#39;volume&#39;: 39602
  },
  {
    &#39;open&#39;: 86.585,
    &#39;high&#39;: 86.585,
    &#39;low&#39;: 86.5239,
    &#39;close&#39;: 86.5239,
    &#39;volume&#39;: 421
  }, .... ]
```

Why does the dataframe change this way, why is timestamp lost?
Also, I want to access these dataframe values to graph them by modifying this function from canvas.js. My plan is to iterate over the Df values similarly to how they iterate over the lines of the CSV. Is this approach possible?

```
function updateChart(csv) {
    var csvLines = points = [];
    csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++) {
        if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
            points = csvLines[i].split(",");
            dataPoints.push({
                x: new Date(
                   //access timestamp value here
                    parseInt(points[0].split("-")[0]),
                    parseInt(points[0].split("-")[1]),
                    parseInt(points[0].split("-")[2])
                ),
                y: [
                  //acces high low open close here
                    parseFloat(points[1]),
                    parseFloat(points[2]),
                    parseFloat(points[3]),
                    parseFloat(points[4])
                ]
            });
        }
    }
    chart.render();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After some frustration I was able to figure it out and here is the answer for anyone who ever comes across this post.

The reason I was not able to access the dataframe properly was because I wasn't converting it to a json format properly. In order to do this I added only a couple lines.

graph.html file:

```
var df = {{df|tojson}};
var jsonObj = eval('[' + df + ']');
```

app.py

```
   return render_template('graph.html', df = df.to_json(), symbol=symbol)
```

In app.py I convert the dataframe into a json string and pass it to graph.html when app.py receives a post request. Then in graph.html it then converts the df into a format for use in JS/html files. This syntax {{var|tojson}} is specific to jinja2, a template engine used by flask. Then I turn the json string into a json object.

Then to read the data and create the graph's datapoints I have the js function as follows:

```
function updateChart(jsonObj) {
var df = {{df|tojson}};
var jsonObj = eval('[' + df + ']');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var timestamp = jsonObj[0].timestamp[i]
        var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
        d.setTime(timestamp);
        console.log(d);
        dataPoints.push({
            x: d,
            y: [
                parseFloat(jsonObj[0].open[i]),
                parseFloat(jsonObj[0].high[i]),
                parseFloat(jsonObj[0].low[i]),
                parseFloat(jsonObj[0].close[i])
            ]
        });
}
chart.render();
```

}
}

This graph is created using the canvas.js library, which uses another function in conjunction with updateChart to create a chart object and then passes the data from updateChart function to the chart object. Hope this helps for anyone else out there working with Flask and JS.